# Prevent user to stop/disable tray agent

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, notification-area

I have a backup client installed in all our organization's machines and I need to be running it in background at every moment and the thing is, some users keep stoping it.
Almost all machines run Windows 7.
I'm actually installing and Active Directory to manage all users so, my question is, is there a way to prevent users disabling the agent?
Maybe with some Active Directory directives or some other way?

Comment: What backup program are you using? Disallowing a user to stop a program is not possible, but usually from the client itself, disabling the program can be done, and most backup clients run as a service, so the tray icon can remain closed and the backup service simply runs in the background. Also, consider to simply tell the people who do so that they shouldn't.

Comment: Run it as an administrator?

Comment: All the users have admin rights?

Comment: You can use group policy to hide the system tray. Or you update your acceptable use policy to remind users that disregarding management's instructions regarding use of company assets is subject to corrective action.

Comment: Synology's backup agent. Already told people that the backuo solution is for their own good but, no luck with that, they keep closing it. Not all users have admin right but some do. I searched group policy's editor 'gpedit' but it doesn't exist on their Windows 7 machines. Maybe after joining them to an AD domain?